# Podcast - tools for creating feeds

Tags: podcasts, feed

I want to change from a streaming server to the Podcast way of distributing our messages. We are a world wide net of churches with 2 and more messages per week and church to be uploaded.

I need some tools to easily create the feed and upload it to our websites, or to automatically create the feed from files on the webserver, using the mp3 tags.

The main criteria: it has to be easy to use for non IT professionals (i.e. pastors), that already stuggle uploading the mp3 files to their servers - but now manage to do so.

Any tools available?

**Edit**: Maybe some more info on what I'ld like: I have a set of mp3-files locally or on a media server. These files have tags that describe them (title, artist, style, year, ...). I would like to have an app that - either locally on demand or on a website dynamically - generates a podcast from this, taking the n most recent files.

Comment: I did this every week for a year for a church, plus ran the streaming.  Do you still have any questions?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a mac there is [Podcast maker](http://www.lemonzdream.com/podcastmaker/)

Comment: Sorry, no mac here - as much as I would like to.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Feedburner](http://www.feedburner.com). This is made for podcasters, so they can easily manage feeds.

Comment: But I want to generate the feed from mp3 files, not just distribute it.

Comment: 152, this is not helpful. The question is how to create the feeds, not how to distribute them.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application, [WordPress](http://wordpress.org) can generate these easily.

From a recent thread on a Linux mailing list I'm on, the following were also suggested:

- http://www.xul.fr/en-xml-rss.html
- http://code.google.com/p/podcast-generator/